# Insert query - looping through array of data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of names. My table structure is:

```
id | name
```

What would be the best way to insert each name from the array in to a separate row in the table?

```
id | name
 1 | John
 2 | James
```

I was thinking about looping through the array in PHP bu there must be a better way?

Comment: This would be the perfect place to use a prepared statement and bound parameters.

Comment: define "best". Do you experience any problem with your current approach at the moment?

Comment: loop the array to create one multivalued `INSERT` statetment, example, `INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (1, 'John'), (2, 'James')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small improvement to @Daryl Gill for `prepare` better practice

```
// List of names to insert
$names = array("Daryl", "AnotherName");

// Prepare once
$sh = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tblname (Name) VALUES (?)");

foreach ($names AS $name){
  $sh->bind_param('s', $name);
  $sh->execute();
}

// Free resource when we're done
$sh->close();
```

Comment: Well, I am not fan of mysqli (most of the time I use PDO). The 's' means the first parameters is a string type. See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 3):

**Using MySQli For Example:**

```
$DB = new mysqli ("Server","username","password","database");

$Array = array("Daryl", "AnotherName");
foreach ($Array AS $Names){
  $Query = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO Table (Name) VALUES (?)");
  $Query->bind_param('s',$Names);
  $Query->execute();
  $Query->close();
}
```

Best possible way would be to loop through the array using a foreach to get the individual values.. Then perform an insert on the current value before looping to the next.